# Filling ListView from fxml file in JavaFX, empty listview

Tags: java, list, listview, javafx

Hello i starting my adventure with javafx, i use SceneBuilder to make theme,
this is my XmlFile:http://pastebin.com/9fvhREKc
controller:

```
public class Controller {

@FXML
private ListView templates;
@FXML
private ImageView image;

@FXML
void initalize() {
    ObservableList elements = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    elements.add("first");
    elements.add("second");
    elements.add("third");
    image.setImage(new Image("file:test.jpg"));
    templates.setItems(elements);
}
```

}
and my main class

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(this.getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
    Controller controller = new Controller();
    loader.setController(controller);
    Pane root = loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}
and when i start application my theme work but list and image is empty;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the controller *before* you load the FXML, since the controller's `initialize` method is invoked as part of the `load()` process:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(this.getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
Controller controller = new Controller();
loader.setController(controller);
Pane root = loader.load();
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
```

Also note you have a typo in your `Controller` class: the method name `initialize` is misspelled. Since the `FXMLLoader` uses reflection to find and execute this method, this will prevent the method from being executed:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ListView templates;
    @FXML
    private ImageView image;

    @FXML
    // void initalize() {
    void initialize() {
        ObservableList elements = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        elements.add("first");
        elements.add("second");
        elements.add("third");
        image.setImage(new Image("file:test.jpg"));
        templates.setItems(elements);
    }

}
```

Comment: i move up this loader.setController before loader.load() but my list is still empty;/

Comment: @Larry Create a [MCVE] (i.e. an application that *just* shows a `ListView`, and nothing else) and post the complete minimal example in your question. If the above doesn't work, something is wrong with code that you haven't posted.

Comment: @Larry Please post the FXML ([properly formatted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)) in the question, instead of posting a link to it.